# Testing htmlencode issue in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, validation, html-encode

In our application developed in html5 and javascript whenever a user submits(with text contain < and > and @) the form (containing a comments text field )we get the following error:

{"Message":"A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client ......

Now the dev team has fixed this issue saying that they handled this at the server side.

Now i want to test different scenarios just to ensure that this issue wont repeat next time and for any other special characters .

Can anyone suggest me the different scenarios i can test here apart from entering the special characters in the  comments text box and submitting the form?

Comment: Do you know how the DEV team "fixed" the issue, because if they set validateRequest="false" in the web.config or in the page directives, then that "fix" just bypasses the server-side check and assumes that everything is properly HTML-encoded; testing the scenarios will not matter, because you won't get the error anymore. 

If the DEV team is actually cleansing the input, then you are in a better position, because now you are truly testing scenarios. I would have a discussion with the developers and ask them what happens when invalid characters are attempted to be sent to the server.

Comment: the code change is[ValidateInput(false)] in the .cs code.